# How does Netfilter understand that packet is RELATED?

Tags: netfilter

`conntrack` match module `--ctstate` argument supports `RELATED` packet state. How does Netfilter know that for example in case of active FTP a connection from FTP server data port(TCP port 20) to the unprivileged data port the client specified earlier, is a `RELATED` connection? Does Netfilter have some modules where each protocol, which is supported by `RELATED`, is described? Last but not least, is there a list of protocols which are supported by this `RELATED` state?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Various Internet Control Message Protocol (ICMP) packets may be "related" to some protocol's connection (or an attempt at such), but these ICMP packets are different than the protocol that caused them, hence the "related" notion. This may happen when a host or firewall rejects a TCP or UDP connection attempt with a destination unreachable ICMP packet; allowing `RELATED` lets that related ICMP packet through. (TCP does have a RST, so may or may not issue a related ICMP response, and firewall admins may or may not allow ICMP replies...)

Application level protocols (such as FTP) will each require a custom module, as custom code is necessary to dig into the packets and figure out whether and how it relates to anything else netfilter knows about. These modules could be written by anyone for any application, though inspecting what `nf_conntrack_*` files are available may be a good place to start for a list:

```
% print -l /lib/modules/3.10.0-327.13.1.el7.x86_64/kernel/net/netfilter/nf_conntrack_*(:t)
nf_conntrack_amanda.ko
nf_conntrack_broadcast.ko
nf_conntrack_ftp.ko
...
```